# Bootstrap 4 modal close button not working first open

Tags: ajax, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

i've a dynamic modal action working with an id. The code works perfectly but the close button works only if the page is refreshed.

My js function with Ajax dynamic :

```
function urlId() {
    //je récupère l'id de l'url
    $('.post .modal-action').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var projet_id = $(this).data('projet_id');
        var $hidennDiv = $('#' + projet_id);
        // j'injecte l'id dans l'url de l'ajax

        $.ajax({
            url: 'core/libs/contents-services.php?action=getModal&id=' + projet_id,
            type: "get",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (reponse) {
                $('#myModal--effect-fullwidth').html(reponse);
                projet_id = reponse.projet_id;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And this is the code of button that closes the modal :

```
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="text-white">x</span>
        </button>
```

This is the link with id's modal :

```
<a href="#myModal--effect-fullwidth" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal--effect-fullwidth" class="btn modal-action text-white"   data-projet_id="'.$contents_brand[ 'projet_id' ].'">Découvrir</a>
```

I'am using this framework : **fezvrasta** (bootstrap material design)

May be i'am missing something or a code in my js function ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution :

add show.bs.modal in my action click in my js function.

Comment: I did not get your solution properly. Will you kindly elaborate it?